# Stripe payments show wrong amount value

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I try add `stripe` payment system to my project like this:

```
<form action="/home/charge" method="POST">
    <script
            src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="${stripePublicKey}"
            data-image="https://orig00.deviantart.net/6c3b/f/2018/149/5/6/pubg_512x512_icon_by_rengatv-dccvgi0.png"
            data-name="Test"
            data-description="Balance"
            data-amount="${amount}"
            data-currency="${currency}"
            data-locale="auto">
    </script>
</form>
```

and pass value:

```
modelAndView.getModel().put("amount", 50*100);
```

But on Stripe wiget I see

[image]

Comment: What's your `currency` set to?

Comment: I try USD and EUR - result is same

Comment: Is there any more code you can add? I'm not seeing the issue

Comment: I am sending 5,000 cents. I expect it to be $ 50 but on the widget I see $0.0.5. When I get a response from Stripe in this response amount = 0

Comment: Yes, which is the minimum amount for the stripe API so it defaults to that. Is there more code that's related to adding the amount? what's `modelAndView` or `getModel()`

Comment: if I set like this `data-amount="5000"` I see normal amount $50.0 but if I set like `data-amount="${amount}"` I see wrong value. I use freemarker tamplate engine(`${amount}` = value `modelAndView.getModel().put("amount", 50*100);`)

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change the currency and amount with JS here? If so, that simply won't work with simple Checkout. You'll need to use the custom integration. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Comment: @duck I just don't understand how it works. in my view it is - I specify the amount in `data-amount="${amount}"` and stripe show this amount on the button. After that I press this button, and if all successfull - I receive response with amount I sent. But in response I get 0. Or I misunderstood everything and the amount is set and shown on the payment button for clarity? and the amount is set again from the database or another source and not from the answer?